# How can I save in example date inputs from another website to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I've developed a 'calendar' system that allows users to submit dates and times using JavaScript from one website to another. However, the system currently only saves the data locally and doesn't work seamlessly on an actual website. The concept behind it is to provide a platform where users can input specific times and additional information on one website, and then have that data seamlessly displayed on another connected website.

The system functions flawlessly within a local context, efficiently saving data using JavaScript. However, upon deploying it to a website, a challenge arises: when other users submit their times, the information remains isolated and doesn't become visible to others, including myself.

Comment: you need a database of some sorts.

Comment: What do you mean by *another connected website*? Connected how?

Comment: @mykaf I mean like from www.website.com/input -> www.website.com/output